# Lp norm attains its minimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, $1\leq p<\infty$. Define $$\|f\|_{min}=\inf\{\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}:a\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

Prove that there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f\|_{min}=\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$.

Thanks for any help.

---

My attempt: I managed to prove for the case of $f$ a simple function, and perhaps one could use the fact that simple functions are dense in $L^p$ to finish it off?

Suppose $f=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\chi_{E_k}$ where $E_k$ are measureable and disjoint, and $a_k>0$. Since $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, $|E_k|<\infty$ for each $k$.

Then
\begin{align*}
\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}&=\left(\int_\Omega\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_{E_k}-a\right|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{E_k}|a_k-a|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k-a|^p|E_k|\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align*}

Clearly, $h(a)=\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ is a continuous non-negative function of $a$, and $h(a)\to\infty$ as $a\to\pm\infty$. Hence, the infimum of $h(a)$ must occur when $a$ lies in some compact subset $[-R,R]$. By Extreme Value Theorem, $h(a)$ attains its minimum on $[-R,R]$, that is, there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f\|_{min}=\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$.

I am kind of stuck here. I know for any $f\in L^p$, there exists simple function $g$ such that $\|f-g\|_{L^p(\Omega)}<\epsilon$, but so far I am not able to use it to finish up the proof. Also, it may be possible that I am on the wrong track entirely and simple functions is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows $|\Omega|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$.

If $|\Omega|=\infty$ then, for $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, we have that 
$\| f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}=\infty$ for any $a\neq 0$ so clearly the infimum is attained at $a=0$.

If $|\Omega|<\infty$ then we use the reverse triangle inequality to get, if $h(a)=\| f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$,
$$
|h(a)-h(b)|\leq \| a-b\|_{L^p(\Omega)} = |\Omega|^{1/p}|a-b|.
$$
This proves the continuity of $h$ and your argument goes through.

Comment: Nice. How do we see that $\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}=\infty$ for any $a\neq 0$? Is it also by reverse triangle inequality $\|f-a\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\geq\left|\|f\|-\|a\|\right|=\infty$?

Comment: @yoyostein: Yes, or the usual triangle inequality: $$a|\Omega|^{1/p}= \| a \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq \| a-f \|_{L^p(\Omega)} + \| f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$